# Does Cloudflare Cache HTML5 Video Embedded on PHP Page?

Tags: php, html, caching, video, cloudflare

I have a php page with an embedded HTML5 video, say video.mp4. On cloudflare, I have a pagerule setup for *mydomain.com/*.php* and set it to cache everything. Will cloudflare cache the embedded video?

Thanks.

EDIT: Apparently cloudflare f***s up when caching videos. If a user watches half a video and cloudflare only caches that, every single visitor to your website will receive half the video.

Answer (score 1):

But where do you want it to cache?  In memory on the cloudflare server, or the user's Browser.  I assume the latter because the former should not matter

have you tried:

```
preload="auto"
```

Check the HTTP Response Header to see if it has

```
Cache-Control: max-age=xxxxx
```

Where xxxxx = number of seconds the Browser should cache.

'Expires' is also a date where the Browser would no longer keep it in cache.

To see the Header, right click, select Inspect Element, go to the "Network Tab" refresh the page, select the video from the list of resources, view the Response Header.

To store the video in memory, the PHP /tmp directory is a memory directory.

To verify the tmp directory use:

```
echo sys_get_temp_dir();
```

**To get the video into the temp directory**

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://example.com/video/test.mp4');

$fp = fopen('/tmp/test.mp4','w');
fwrite($fp,$data);
fclose($fp);
```

You may need to set a handler for content-type: video/mp4.
But the type on the video control should do it.  As I recall I had to set the handler, so the HTTP response header had the correct content type.

```
<source src="/tmp/test.mp4" type="video/mp4";/>
```

You could make a PHP script to server the mp4 with the correct header.

```
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
echo file_get_contents('/tmp/test.mp4');
```

Then in the video control:

```
src="video.php"
```

Comment: The former could matter if I wanted to reduce the load on my server and make cloudflare handle it instead.

Comment: You can cache it on your sever, and maybe Cloudflare. I do not know what capabilities you have on cloudflare, like running PHP scripts.  If you can run PHP on cloudeflare and have enough memory to store it in, there is a way to ensure the video comes from the server memory. I'll update my anwser.

Comment: Wait, from my server memory, or cloudflare's?

Comment: Wow, that's a nice solution, but it wouldn't really work for me. It'd be a bitch to set up for the number of videos that I have.

Answer (score 0):

How come you don't have the PageRule set to mydomain.com/* to cache everything?

"Will cloudflare cache the embedded video?"

But, yes, the PageRule should cache everything.